# Restrict users in intranet to access websites like facebook,linkedin etc

Tags: asp.net, proxy, dns, intranet

I want to restrict my intranet users in such a way that I provide them userId & password of websites (such as LinkedIn, Facebook, Gmail, Twitter etc) only these logins should be allowed.

**If any user tries to use another userID then it should block all such users to access above mentioned websites.**

I am not sure how this should be achieved. But here I am trying to develop a web application using Asp.net that will Log-In to websites with default credentials & save the session cookies in browser then user will be redirected to relative website, which will have user session in cookies. Also I'll block Login page of websites for rest of users/systems on CC Proxy.

Please guide me in right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Usually i'll flash my modem for Force-DNS

Comment: I studied little bit about this, but this redirect whole website i guess. Or can I redirect specific web page also?

Answer (score 0):

I think DNS will be a bad option for you, it will be easy to bypass and you could not redirect specific web page.
I think the answer to your question will be proxy, with proxy you will be able to supervise thier web actions completely.
They will still be able to bypass it but I believe it will be hard enough

Comment: how do we restrict them to use only company social accounts using proxy as well. In proxy either we allow them a site/a webpage or we dont. Let me know if there is any proxy software which can be used for this. Else we have to create web proxy or something else.